# how to select integer columns through list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list

I have a dataframe with columns as mentioned

```
[-10800,
 -9000,
 -7200,
 -5400,
 -3600,
 -1800,
 0,
 180,
 300,
 1200,
 1800,
 2400,
 3600,
 '-10800_R',
 '-9000_R',
 '-7200_R',
 '-5400_R',
 '-3600_R',
 '-1800_R',
 '0_R',
 '180_R',
 '300_R',
 '1200_R',
 '1800_R',
 '2400_R',
 '3600_R']
```

I want to only select the '_R' columns

I am using list comprehension

```
[i for i in df.columns.to_list() if '_R' in i]
```

but i am getting the error of

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Before testingif _R is in it, test if it is a string (isintanceof)

Comment: Instead of `if '_R' in i`, which will only work on strings and will of course crash if an `int` is encountered, you have to check if `i` is a `str` before checking if there's a particular string in it. Or you could just check if `i` is an `int` which seems much more straightforward. This would be done via `instanceof()` of course.

Comment: without type-check `str(i).endswith('_R')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @nacho's comment:

```
[i for i in df.columns.to_list() if isinstance(i,str) and i.endswith("_R")]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a check that `i` is a string:

```py
[i for i in df.columns.to_list() if isinstance(i, str) and '_R' in i]
```